# Origin of "oontz"

Tags: history, onomatopoeia

I saw the word here and there and inferred ([correctly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oontz)) that it must signify a mechanical beat in music. Anything known about the origin (which surely can't be older than techno - note that the word itself, in the alternative sense "game of craps", exists for longer)? Earliest spotting given in same link is 1999, which is *far* younger than techno.

Comment: This probably belongs on English Language and Usage SE which normally handles obscure etymological questions. It's obviously onomatopoeic but I suspect it'll require a lengthy trawl through sources to find an earlier occurrence (and unfortunately 1999 is near the start of the internet, though maybe it was used on Usenet for a while before).

Comment: I see that ***all*** the Wiktionary citations for the "mechanical beat in music" sense feature two or three repetitions of the "word". Hardly anyone would recognize the intended sense if it ***wasn't*** used like that (in a way that *accurately and literally* reflects the meaning! :) The (totally unrelated, I'm sure) "game of craps" sense never had much currency, and there's no such "word" in the full OED.

Comment: Onomatopoeia gives us a whole category of "not-really-official-words, just sounds." For instance, I've heard the loud, reverb-rich snare sound of an 80s power ballad described as "dooj." But this kind of [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) usage doesn't really lend itself to etymology. If I used it and you understood me, why try to figure out why I used it?

Comment: @StuartF: Feel free to move it (or someone else) - and (being an Internet ancient) I share your reservations on accessability.